# Argument of type '...' is not assignable to parameter of type '...' TS 2345

Tags: typescript

Given the following:

```js
interface MyInterface {
  type: string;
}

let arr: object[] = [ {type: 'asdf'}, {type: 'qwerty'}]

// Alphabetical sort
arr.sort((a: MyInterface, b: MyInterface) => {
      if (a.type < b.type) return -1;
      if (a.type > b.type) return 1;
      return 0;
    });
```

Can someone help decipher the TS error:

```js
// TypeScript Error
[ts]
Argument of type '(a: MyInterface, b: MyInterface) => 0 | 1 | -1' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: object, b: object) => number'.
  Types of parameters 'a' and 'a' are incompatible.
    Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'MyInterface': type [2345]
```

Comment: Can't reproduce with the posted code. `let arr:object[]` is the only way I can reproduce the error ..

Comment: cant reproduce the error. [see this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20MyInterface%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20arr%20%3D%20%5B%20%7Btype%3A%20'zasdf'%7D%2C%20%7Btype%3A%20'qwerty'%7D%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Alphabetical%20sort%0D%0Aarr.sort((a%3A%20MyInterface%2C%20b%3A%20MyInterface)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(a.type%20%3C%20b.type)%20return%20-1%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(a.type%20%3E%20b.type)%20return%201%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%200%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B)

Comment: Isn't `object[]` the equivalent to the array of objects shown? In any case, I've updated the original post to include the type for `arr`

Comment: No it is not. If you leave out the type, TS infers it, so the type of `arr` will be `{type: string;}[]` and you don't get the error. If you set it to `object` the you get the error since the argument to the callback are not compatible with `object`.

Comment: So essentially, the correct answer is to `let arr: [MyInterface]` ?

Comment: Be careful : it's `let arr: MyInterface[]`. Otherwise, it's a tuple in Typescript

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is a simplified example to reproduce the error:

```
interface MyInterface {
  type: string;
}
let arr:object[] = []
// Error: "object" is not compatible with MyInterface 
arr.sort((a: MyInterface, b: MyInterface) => {});
```

The reason its an error is because `object` cannot be assigned to something that is of type `MyInterface`:

```
interface MyInterface {
  type: string;
}
declare let foo: object;
declare let bar: MyInterface;
// ERROR: object not assignable to MyInterface
bar = foo;
```

And the reason this is an error is because `object` is synonymous with `{}`. `{}` does not have the `type` property and therefore incompatible with MyInterface.

## Fix

Perhaps you meant to use `any` (instead of `object`). `any` is compatible with *everything*.

## Better fix

Use the exact type i.e. `MyInterface`

```
interface MyInterface {
  type: string;
}
let arr:MyInterface[] = []; // Add correct annotation 
arr.sort((a: MyInterface, b: MyInterface) => {});
```

Answer (score 0):

If an object is already of a defined type it may cause this error.

```
// does not work
var user = aws.results.Item;
user = getUserType(user);
doSomething(user);

// works
var user = aws.results.Item;
var userTyped = getUserType(user);
doSomething(userTyped);

// typed user parameter
function doSomething(user: User) {}
```

Instead of reusing an existing reference create a new one.