# Generics T extends U but Readonly<T> does not

Tags: typescript, generics

IMHO, this is *not* a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71978472/argument-of-type-readonly-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type). Here is a minimal example:

```js
class Indexer {
  private readonly someIndex = 200;
  public getIndex() { return this.someIndex; }
}

class Person extends Indexer {}
class Something<T extends Indexer> {
  s = new Map<number, T>();
  insert(t: T){ /* ... */ }
}

const c1 = new Something<         Person >();
const c2 = new Something<Readonly<Person>>();
```

- On one hand my class needs to subclass `Indexer`
- On the other hand it needs to be `Readonly`

I can not achieve the two properties together:

```
$ npx tsc --target es2020 main.ts
main.ts:13:26 - error TS2344: Type 'Readonly<Person>' does not satisfy the constraint 'Indexer'.
  Property 'someIndex' is missing in type 'Readonly<Person>' but required in type 'Indexer'.

13 const c2 = new Something<Readonly<Person>>();
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  main.ts:2:20
    2   private readonly someIndex = 200;
                         ~~~~~~~~~
    'someIndex' is declared here.
```

Comment: Does just making `Something` like `class Something<T extends Readonly<Indexer>>` work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't work because `Readonly` is a mapped type and mapped types are dropping the private keys.

Thus the error you get :

```
Type 'Readonly<Person>' does not satisfy the constraint 'Indexer'.
  Property 'someIndex' is missing in type 'Readonly<Person>' but required in type 'Indexer'.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECSB2ATApgD2QJ2gbwFDWgAcMBLANzABdloNkxEB7eEAT2gkYFtkEVVoAXmgAmAAxiA3PiIBXAEYgSwaAHNklPmgAUAShy0NsjPGiUAFiQgA6Tjy2pJ0AL65XuSq0I0AYo0ZC0ABK9EwsrAA8AAqYnPAAfLgA9EkE0AB6APy4uKCQMDEYcdBo1EgwDpg4rnlQ0ADK3BqW8KoRAColqGWIFUhomPE4MjDC8MgA7tAAsmCEEfCyXPKYADTQ7fF60gQk8BCYlNqUAFwbutjQSQBU0Nb30Nepru7AzBCU0MAAjIHjU40eBY9m00mCCIViltdNI3vtPsARH9Jg0msDWhEQgxmGxorFmPFoZIgA)